# How do I alter a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, alter-table

I have a table `WC_C` with column `C_S(varchar(2))`. I need to add a new column in this same table `R_S(varchar(2))` and move the contents of `C_S` which has values `A, C, D` to column `R_S`.

How do I do it?

---

Requirement:

- Table ------------------ `WC_C`
- existing column ---- `C_S`  contains values `A, B, C, D, E, F`
- new column --------- `R_S`  Should contain  `A, C, D` from `C_S` column.

Comment: What do you mean by `PL SQL`? [PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) is used in Oracle DBMS, **not** MySQL.

Comment: altering a table programmatically makes my red alert siren go red and ring like mad :) are you sure you need that?

Answer (score 2):

Using MySQL syntax since you tagged your question with it...

Add new column `R_S`:

```
alter table WC_C add R_S VARCHAR(2);
```

Insert data into new column:

```
insert into WC_C (R_S) select C_S from WC_C where C_S IN ('A', 'C', 'D');
```

**Note:** I haven't tested the above queries. Use with discretion.

Comment: The Oracle syntax is the same, but I'd use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR` to define the column.